# Load Testing for an Intranet website which has Static URL

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

we are having a intranet website which has the static URL ( example.com/index.php) which will never change when we navigate or perform actions inside the website. All the actions we do will be performed inside Iframes and the URL remains same for all the pages.

Is it possible to do Load Testing for this kind of website? I want to try out Jmeter for Load Testing, but not sure if it is suitable for my scenario.
Also please suggest if any other Open Source Tools available for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the performance testing tools I'm currently aware of doesn't know anything about iframes, DOM, styles, scripts, etc. They operate on protocol level, for particularly HTTP load testing tools send GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/etc. requests and measure response time. So performance testing assumes the following steps:

1. Creating test sceleton (record or manual development)
2. Correlaction (getting dynamic parameters from previous request and adding them to the next one)
3. Parametrization (once test is working fine for 1 virtual user more users and data can be added.
4. Run the test
5. Analyze results

In regards to JMeter world:

1. To record your test scenario - [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. For correlation:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
3. Parametrization

   - [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
   - Various samplers and functions allowing reading files, perform database queries, generating random integers,strings,etc.

For the most popular open source testing tools:

1. [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
3. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

For above tools main features comparison and review see [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article.